# Kubernetes dashboard keeps pending with message: no endpoints available for service "kubernetes-dashboard"

Tags: kubernetes, coreos

Heeey all, I need some help with getting the dashboard to work. My dashboard pod  has status "Pending" and if I do a curl call to http://127.0.0.1:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard then I get this result:

"no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\""

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

All pods

```
core@helena-coreos ~ $ ./kubectl get po --namespace=kube-system
NAME                                     READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kube-apiserver-146.185.128.27            1/1       Running   0          5d
kube-apiserver-37.139.31.151             1/1       Running   0          7d
kube-controller-manager-146.185.128.27   1/1       Running   0          19h
kube-controller-manager-37.139.31.151    1/1       Running   0          16h
kube-dns-v11-ika0m                       0/4       Pending   0          19h
kube-proxy-146.185.128.27                1/1       Running   0          5d
kubernetes-dashboard-1775839595-1h0lt    0/1       Pending   0          19h
```

Describe pod:

```
core@helena-coreos ~ $ ./kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-1775839595-1h0lt --namespace="kube-system"
Name:       kubernetes-dashboard-1775839595-1h0lt
Namespace:  kube-system
Node:       /
Labels:     app=kubernetes-dashboard,pod-template-hash=1775839595
Status:     Pending
IP:     
Controllers:    ReplicaSet/kubernetes-dashboard-1775839595
Containers:
  kubernetes-dashboard:
    Image:  gcr.io/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.1.0
    Port:   9090/TCP
    QoS Tier:
      cpu:  BestEffort
      memory:   BestEffort
    Liveness:   http-get http://:9090/ delay=30s timeout=30s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment Variables:
Volumes:
  default-token-mn7e9:
    Type:   Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName: default-token-mn7e9
No events.
```

Service configuration:

```
core@helena-coreos ~ $ ./kubectl get svc kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: 2016-07-10T22:25:03Z
  labels:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "58669"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: 25d56060-46ed-11e6-9817-040124359901
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.3.0.67
  ports:
  - nodePort: 32014
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

I also tried to find some logs:

```
core@helena-coreos ~ $ ./kubectl logs kubernetes-dashboard-1775839595-1h0lt --namespace=kube-system
core@helena-coreos ~ $
```

I've got a really hard time to figure out why things are pending

Already thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a scheduler running so it can't schedule any containers.

Answer (score 5):

The other possibility is that you have no resources in the cluster and the scheduler fails to schedule the Dashboard UI. If this is true you can see this in cluster events (`kubectl get events --namespace=kube-system`).

Comment: Its wasnt the answer but still thanks for the tip. Ill probably need it for in the future ;)