# kubernetes dashboard unavailable post cluster deploy

Tags: vagrant, kubernetes

i am new to kubernetes.  i have just followed this guide and have a vagrant/kubernetes cluster: https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-vagrant.html

i was interested viewing the ui, so i followed the instructions here: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/ui/#deploying-the-dashboard-ui

```
$ kubectl proxy
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:8001
```

upon browsing to the above IP:PORT, `<h3>Unauthorized</h3>` is served.  so, i suffix `/ui` to the URI, and we get:

```
// 127.0.0.1:8001/ui redirected to http://localhost:8001/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "no endpoints available for service \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "ServiceUnavailable",
  "code": 503
}
```

perhaps relevant is:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://172.17.4.101:443
Heapster is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/heapster
KubeDNS is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns
kubernetes-dashboard is running at https://172.17.4.101:443/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard

$ kubectl get services
NAME         CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
kubernetes   10.3.0.1     <none>        443/TCP   36m
```

i saw another SO thread, [Kubernetes dashboard keeps pending with message: no endpoints available for service "kubernetes-dashboard"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38411595/kubernetes-dashboard-keeps-pending-with-message-no-endpoints-available-for-serv), and discovered `get pods` and `describe pod <pod-name> --namespace=kube-system`.

so, i ran `kubectl describe pod kubernetes-dashboard-3543765157-94gj9  --namespace="kube-system"` which yielded: https://gist.github.com/cdaringe/b972bf5a95c9f2a7cb8386ef6bf2252b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ultimately, my cluster had no nodes, so the UI service had no place to land and run!  the API still attempts to proxy to it, which is why it reported "no endpoints"--there was no host endpoint serving the content.  still haven't figured out why my vagrant cluster deployed no nodes.  im going to guess that the workers never downloaded the kubelet and joined.